# Enable post excerpts in wordpress theme twentythirteen

Tags: theme-twenty-thirteen

How do I enable excerpts in the theme?Currently excerpts are only displayed on the search page but I would like to enable them on tag and category pages.

Comment: Made an update with my answer. If that helped your cause, don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In TwentyThirteen, there are many files, their names're started with `content`:

1. content.php
2. content-none.php
3. content-aside.php
4. content-audio.php
5. content-chat.php
6. content-gallery.php
7. content-image.php
8. content-link.php
9. content-quote.php
10. content-status.php
11. content-video.php

Among them, except the first two, all the others are for different post types, and you can understand their usages from their names.

The 2nd one, `content-none.php` is used to display apology texts, when there is no content found with a query. And the 1st one, `content.php` is used in various display pages with two conditions, where:

- `is_search()` — is to check whether it is the search result page
- `is_single()` — is to check whether it is the post details page

If you open the `index.php`, you will find a code:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

Here the template part (`content.php`) is called.

#### Answer

So, to show excerpt in your front page or home page, you will need to modify `content.php`. Like the `is_search()`, `is_single()`, there are several other checkers in WordPress:

- `is_home()` — is to check whether it is the home page
- `is_front_page()` — is to check whether it is the front-page
- `is_category()` — is to check whether it is the category archive page
- `is_archive()` — is to check whether it is the general archive page
- `is_tag()` — is to check whether it is the tags archive page
- ...so on

And you may know that, to enable excerpt instead of full content, you will have to change the code `the_content()` to `the_excerpt()`.

#### More Details

- [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)
- [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt%E2%80%8E)
- [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content)

### EDIT

Yep, @Rarst said a very important thing that, if you make change into any public theme, the changes will be wiped out when a new update will take place. So, to put your modifications in place, you have to make a Child Theme on TwentyThirteen. A Child Theme is nothing but a new folder with a stylesheet. You can get that at:

- [**Child Themes** - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: While explanation is sound the better _action_ to take would be creating child theme with the changes, otherwise 2013 updates will wipe changes out.

Comment: @Rarst Thank you for reminding such an important issue. Edited the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: You are free to accept the answer. Just click on the check mark on the left to any answer. :)